# Python - how to loop over the elements returned by this function?

Tags: python

I just started learning python. I am now trying to apply my knowledge to modify [some code I found online](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/python_examples/face_landmark_detection.py)
The function shape.part(i) returns a point (x,y) on an image.  I am now trying to write each of those points on an individial line to a file. But for some reason the for loop always generates runtime errors, no matter whether I used

```
   - range(len(shape.part() ))
   - enum(len(shape.part() ))
   - enum(shape.part() ))
   - ....
```

Could somebody show me what is the correct way to do this and explain why what I've tried didn't work?

Thanks

The piece of code I am trying to get to work:

```
filePts = open('myFile.pts','w')
filePts.write('version: 1'+'\n'+'n_points:  68'+'\n'+'{')

for k, d in enumerate(dets):
    print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom: {}".format(k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
    # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
    shape = predictor(img, d)
    print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {} ...".format(shape.part(0),shape.part(1)))
    # Write output to file
    for i in enumerate(( shape.part() )):  # <----- This is  what fails and am trying to fix 
        print('i: '+ str(i))
        coordLandMark = str(shape.part(i))
        coordLandMark = coordLandMark[1:]
        coordLandMark = coordLandMark.replace(", ", " ")
        coordLandMark = coordLandMark.replace(")", "")
        filePts.write(coordLandMark+'\n')

    # Draw the face landmarks on the screen.
    win.add_overlay(shape)

filePts.write('}\n')
```

Comment: If `shape.part` returns a single point, what do you mean by looping over it? You can't iterate over a singular thing.

Comment: As for the rest of the code, `enum` doesn't exist, and when you iterate over a sequence the variable represents the actual item, not the index, so you just reference the item: `for i in whatever: coordLandMark = str(i)`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well shape.part(1), shape.pat(2), ... prints what I need I'd like it to print every value there is using a loop.

Comment: @gihidoma if you check my answer down there I'm pretty sure it should do what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

hi try this may be you looking for it

```
for row in range(0,len(shape.part() )):
    print row
```

Comment: How's that different from the first line of his question?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, in Python you iterate over the thing itself. So, assuming `shape.part()` returns some kind of sequence:

```
for coordLandMark in shape.part():
    coordLandMark = coordLandMark[1:]
    coordLandMark = coordLandMark.replace(", ", " ")
    coordLandMark = coordLandMark.replace(")", "")
    filePts.write(coordLandMark+'\n')
```

Note, I don't actually know what `shape.part()` returns. If you need more help, you'll need to post a link to the documentation of whatever that object is. There might well be a different method you need to call on `shape` to get something you can iterate over.

Comment: I tried:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25208674/
Which returns: File "./face_landmark_detection.py", line 90, in <module>
    for i in shape.part:
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable

Comment: Well that is not surprising, seeing as the code you ran has nothing to do with what I posted.

Comment: I wrote: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25208727/ and this returns: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./face_landmark_detection.py", line 90, in <module>
    for coordLandMark in shape.part():
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    full_object_detection.part(full_object_detection)
did not match C++ signature:
    part(dlib::full_object_detection, unsigned long idx)

Comment: A function isn't an iterable object... Hence the `TypeError: "instancemethod" not iterable`

Comment: The *result* of a function certainly can be an iterable object. We just need to know which one to call to get a list of points. `shape.parts()` maybe? This would be easier if we had some documentation for the relevant library.

Comment: Note that I posted the github source of the code in the main post

Comment: Yes but not a link to any documentation for the Python API. Is there any?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you like at the 12th line of code that reads `coordLandMark = str(shape.part(i))`, clearly the method is called with an integer (as opposed to nothing in the `for` starting line). Furthermore, line 8 of the code clearly shows that the idea is to do something with every value of `shape.part(i)`, `i` going from 0 to a certain number depending on the image, I'm guessing. So clearly, `shape.part()` won't be an iterable.
And really, it's not me saying the problem is in `shape.part()` not being iterable: it's Python, with the lovely error it raises.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot iterate over a function like that in Python, you can only iterate over lists, tuples, strings, and other `iterable` objects. I believe what you want to do is run the function for many values? Like suggested by your `print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {} ...".format(shape.part(0), shape.part(1)))` line. Therefore what you should do is something like:

```
for i in range(some_value):
    coordLandMark = str(shape.part(i))
    # Do other things you need to do
```

The problem now is for you to find how many items you need to iterate over (the `some_value` in my code). I can't really help more on that matter without more information...